# SQLite Foreign keys not working correctly

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, sqlitemanager

The following is a query for creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "FacilityRating"(
    "FacilityRatingId" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "Stars" VARCHAR,
    "Facility_FacilityId" INTEGER,
    "User_UserId" INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (Facility_FacilityId)
        REFERENCES Facility(FacilityId)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (User_UserId)
        REFERENCES User(UserId)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

However, when I insert a new row in `Facility_FacilityId` and `User_UserId` with some random numbers, SQLite does not give error but adds it anyway.

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Any hint what is going on here? I am using SQLite Manager, an Add-on for Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Have you enabled foreign keys with `PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;`?

Comment: no i have not
how does that work??
how can i turn on foreign keys ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) says:

> Foreign key constraints must be enabled by the application at runtime, using the [PRAGMA foreign_keys](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) command. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> ```
>
> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.